# What does the EndpointsServlet class do in Google's Endpoints?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, web.xml

First, I am a beginner in java servlets, maven projects and apis.

I am doing the following [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java#code) on getting started with google endpoints, which is a tutorial implementing the following maven project [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend) on github. On the web.xml, there is only one named Servlet, the EndpointsServlet like so:

```
<!-- wrap the backend with Endpoints Framework v2. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.echo.Echo</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

What I dont understand is why are there no other servlets on the project? There are only [3 java classes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend/src/main/java/com/example/echo) in the main directory and none of them are servlet files. I am assuming that this project is a sample api with server side logic (such as routing and responding to requests) like any other servlet project which means there should be more than this servlet.

The comment on the web.xml is an obvious clue as to what it does but I dont really know what wrapping the backend with endpoints framework means. Also, I actually got the EndpointsServlet.java file and it says the servlet is a "handler for proxy-less API serving. This servlet understands and replies in JSON-REST. Again, I dont really understand this comment nor what the servlet does even reading it. Servlet code below:

```
package com.google.api.server.spi;

import com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.EndpointNode;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiConfigException;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.model.ApiClassConfig.MethodConfigMap;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.model.ApiConfig;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.model.ApiMethodConfig;
import com.google.api.server.spi.dispatcher.PathDispatcher;
import com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.ApiProxyHandler;
import com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.CorsHandler;
import com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler;
import com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.ExplorerHandler;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * A handler for proxy-less API serving. This servlet understands and replies in JSON-REST.
 */
public class EndpointsServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final String EXPLORER_PATH = "explorer";

  private ServletInitializationParameters initParameters;
  private SystemService systemService;
  private PathDispatcher<EndpointsContext> dispatcher;
  private CorsHandler corsHandler;

  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    this.initParameters = ServletInitializationParameters.fromServletConfig(config, classLoader);
    this.systemService = createSystemService(classLoader, initParameters);
    this.dispatcher = createDispatcher();
    this.corsHandler = new CorsHandler();
  }

  @Override
  public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String method = getRequestMethod(request);
    if ("OPTIONS".equals(method)) {
      corsHandler.handle(request, response);
    } else {
      String path = Strings.stripSlash(
          request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getServletPath().length()));
      EndpointsContext context = new EndpointsContext(method, path, request, response,
          initParameters.isPrettyPrintEnabled());
      if (!dispatcher.dispatch(method, path, context)) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        response.getWriter().append("Not Found");
      }
    }
  }

  private String getRequestMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    String methodOverride = null;
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
      if (headerName.toLowerCase().equals("x-http-method-override")) {
        methodOverride = request.getHeader(headerName);
        break;
      }
    }
    return methodOverride != null ? methodOverride.toUpperCase() : request.getMethod();
  }

  private PathDispatcher<EndpointsContext> createDispatcher() {
    PathDispatcher.Builder<EndpointsContext> builder = PathDispatcher.builder();
    List<EndpointNode> endpoints = systemService.getEndpoints();
    // We're building an ImmutableList here, because it will eventually be used for JSON-RPC.
    ImmutableList.Builder<EndpointsMethodHandler> handlersBuilder = ImmutableList.builder();
    for (EndpointNode endpoint : endpoints) {
      ApiConfig apiConfig = endpoint.getConfig();
      MethodConfigMap methods = apiConfig.getApiClassConfig().getMethods();
      for (Entry<EndpointMethod, ApiMethodConfig> methodEntry : methods.entrySet()) {
        if (!methodEntry.getValue().isIgnored()) {
          handlersBuilder.add(
              new EndpointsMethodHandler(initParameters, getServletContext(), methodEntry.getKey(),
                  apiConfig, methodEntry.getValue(), systemService));
        }
      }
    }
    ImmutableList<EndpointsMethodHandler> handlers = handlersBuilder.build();
    for (EndpointsMethodHandler handler : handlers) {
      builder.add(handler.getRestMethod(), Strings.stripTrailingSlash(handler.getRestPath()),
          handler.getRestHandler());
    }
    ExplorerHandler explorerHandler = new ExplorerHandler();
    builder.add("GET", EXPLORER_PATH, explorerHandler);
    builder.add("GET", EXPLORER_PATH + "/", explorerHandler);
    builder.add("GET", "static/proxy.html", new ApiProxyHandler());
    return builder.build();
  }

  private SystemService createSystemService(ClassLoader classLoader,
      ServletInitializationParameters initParameters) throws ServletException {
    try {
      SystemService.Builder builder = SystemService.builder()
          .withDefaults(classLoader)
          .setStandardConfigLoader(classLoader)
          .setIllegalArgumentIsBackendError(initParameters.isIllegalArgumentBackendError())
          .setDiscoveryServiceEnabled(true);
      for (Class<?> serviceClass : initParameters.getServiceClasses()) {
        builder.addService(serviceClass, createService(serviceClass));
      }
      return builder.build();
    } catch (ApiConfigException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new ServletException(e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of the specified service class.
   *
   * @param serviceClass the class of the service to create
   */
  protected <T> T createService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
    try {
      return serviceClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          String.format("Cannot instantiate service class: %s", serviceClass.getName()), e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          String.format("Cannot access service class: %s", serviceClass.getName()), e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EndpointsServlet` handles all API calls with a certain path prefix. It takes a RESTful API call and translates it into POJO(s) and dispatches it to a Java method you've written, and then serializes the return value of that method to JSON. It does this based on how you annotate your code.

Comment: Thank you @saiyr does that mean I never actually need to create my own Servlet classes anymore? In other words, EndpointsServlet class does all the dispatching to the methods that I have written and all I need to do is write the methods with annotation?

Comment: Yep, as far as APIs go.

Comment: OK it's solve, but maybe there's an interesting story to tell.
AS suggest me to give up on the public declaration for my constructor.
and as many AS suggestions I just do it ,in half automatic mode  and forget about it.what AS can't understand that this is my server class ,so after an hour or two when I back to testing my endpoints..I start getting a weird error messages that the access to my class is deny.
checking everywhere in the cloud for permissions error , and can't find one.
 finally found out that my constructor need to back to public even so,.. AS suggest me otherwise.